# Open converted result in new window

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I want to convert doc to html and browsing through many sites,I came up with this piece of code which works as needed.

```
 Protected Sub Upload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim missingType As Object = Type.Missing
    Dim readOnlyObject As Object = True
    Dim isVisible As Object = False
    Dim documentFormat As Object = 8
    Dim randomName As String = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString
    Dim htmlFilePath As Object = (Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") _
                & (randomName + ".htm"))
    Dim directoryPath As String = (Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") _
                & (randomName + "_files"))

    'Upload the word document and save to Temp folder
    FileUpload1.SaveAs((Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)))
    Dim fileName As Object = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
    Dim applicationclass As ApplicationClass = New ApplicationClass
    applicationclass.Documents.Open(fileName)
    applicationclass.Visible = False
    Dim document As Document = applicationclass.ActiveDocument

    'Save the word document as HTML file
    document.SaveAs(htmlFilePath, documentFormat)

    'Close the word document
    document.Close()

    'Delete the Uploaded Word File
    File.Delete((Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)))
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(htmlFilePath.ToString, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim reader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(fs)
    bytes = reader.ReadBytes(CType(fs.Length, Integer))
    fs.Close()
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
    Response.Flush()
    System.IO.File.Delete(htmlFilePath.ToString)
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

I'm calling this method on the button click

```
 <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button runat="server"  ID="btnUpload"  Text="Upload"  onClick="Upload"    />
    </div>
```

The result of the conversion appears on the same screen. I want it to be opened in a new window.Will be really glad if anyone help me with this.

Comment: You really like `Object` don't you? :) From where are you calling this method? This seems to be missing from the question

Comment: oh yeah ..I'm calling in on this button click <div>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button runat="server"  ID="btnUpload"  Text="Upload"  onClick="Upload"    />
        </div>

Comment: The target attribute solves this problem, but,I'm not using <form> in my application. Is there any alternate way to do it?